# How to delete this event from snort sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, snort

How can we delete this event from snort sql ?

[image]

I tried this:

Create a sql file on Snort machine : nano dbclean.sql

Add the following code to the sql file:

```
use snort;
DELETE FROM event WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 28 DAY);
DELETE FROM data    USING data    LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM iphdr   USING iphdr   LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM icmphdr USING icmphdr LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM tcphdr  USING tcphdr  LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM udphdr  USING udphdr  LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM opt     USING opt     LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM acid_event USING acid_event LEFT OUTER JOIN event USING (sid,cid) WHERE event.sid IS NULL;
DELETE FROM ag USING acid_ag_alert AS ag LEFT OUTER JOIN event AS e ON ag.ag_sid=e.sid AND ag.ag_cid=e.cid WHERE e.sid IS NULL;
OPTIMIZE TABLE event, data, iphdr, icmphdr, tcphdr, udphdr, opt, acid_event, acid_ag_alert;
```

2. Next:

   ```
   mysql -h YOUR-DB-HOST -uYOUR-DB-USER -pYOUR-DB-PASSWORD < dbclean.sql
   ```

But didn't work.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way in order to delete all records from your database using terminal:

```
DATABASE_NAME='snort';DBUSER='YourUser'; DBPASSWORD='YourPassword' ; mysql -Nse 'show tables' -D $DATABASE_NAME -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASSWORD | while read table; do echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;truncate table \`$table\`;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"; done | mysql $DATABASE_NAME -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASSWORD
```